# Return value without close the window wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, window

I want to have a return value from my WPF window without close it.

I have an DLL with WPF usercontrol inside, I call it from my DLL code.
I have to call it, it returns me datas, then I send it datas.
But I don't want to create two different instance of the same window.

My code :

```
        MP.UserControl1 a = new MP.UserControl1();
        a.ShowDialog();

        if (a.DialogResult.HasValue && a.DialogResult.Value == true)
        {
            a.Hide();
            InitialDatas = a.inputData;
        }
        else
            return 0;
```

Then I elaborate InitialDatas

And now I want to call a method inside my "a", and show it again, without create a new window.

Code :

```
        a.SetValue(result, off1, InitialDatas);
        a.ShowDialog();
```

I got error message : Cannot set visibility or call Show, ShowDialog or EnsureHandle after a window has been closed
Is it possible to solve?

Comment: Do the dialog have to be Modal? Why not store the data/result in a ViewModel and simply create a new instance of the dialog and point it to the same ViewModel instance?

Answer (score 3):

I would solve this with an event model. You could do the following:

- Create an event in the Form
- Create an event handler in the caller
- Subscribe to the event and do your logic

The called form:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object source, EventArgs e);

    public class MyForm : Form
    {
        public event MyEventHandler OnInitialData;

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             OnInitialData?.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

In your other Form:

```
MP.UserControl1 a = new MP.UserControl1();
a.OnInitialData += UCA_OnInitialData;

private void UCA_OnInitialData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MP.UserControl1 a = sender as MP.UserControl1;
    a.SetValue(result, off1, a.inputData);
}
a.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, you *cannot* close the window and then open it again.

Instead of closing a window you could hide it by calling the `Hide()` method and then showing it again by calling the `Show()` method.

But since the `ShowDialog()` method doesn't return until the window has been closed, this won't work for a dialog window though. If you require a modal window, you will have to create a new instance of the window and open this one. This shouldn't really be an issue though.

So I guess the answer to your question is simply no. You cannot re-open a closed dialog window.